# Angular OIDC, how to check if user is already logged in

Tags: angular, openid-connect

I have an app in Angular that's connecting to Identity Server SSO, I can log in the user but when I open new browser tab and go to the app the user is not authenticated on this new  instance.

This is my user manager config and constructor in auth service.

```
private authNavStatusSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
authNavStatus$ = this.authNavStatusSource.asObservable();

private manager = new UserManager
({
  authority: this.configService.AuthAppUri,
  client_id: 'angular_spa',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
  response_type: "code",
  scope: "openid profile email api.read",
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true
});

private user: User | null;

constructor(private configService: ConfigService)
{ 
  super();

  this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
    this.user = user;
    console.log(this.user);
    this.authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
  });
}
```

I logged in with "remember me" option enabled and on the Identity Server app the user is still logged in when I close the tab and/or open the app in new one so I don't really know why it's not the same for the Angular client.

How can I check if user is logged in immediately after he goes to my app without redirecting him to SSO and back?

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTTPS instead of HTTP as some of the tokens will not be included in requests sent over HTTP.

The Secure and SameSite attribute prevents cookies to be included in HTTP requests.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: So basically I can't use cookies in angular app unless I have ssl certificate? Is there other way to get this information from oidc? Or do I have to create new endpoint in Identity Server app that just returns that info?

Comment: You should always use HTTPs today 2021/2022, there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: I am now using HTTPs but it still doesn't work. getUser method returns null user even though I see cookies getting created.

Comment: The cookies will always be created, but might not be included in the folllowing requests after the cookie is set in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the JWT token (http://jwt.ms) the identity server sends to the client. It contains claims. One of them is the user name. You need to find out, how this claim is called ("type" property) and then map it to the Angular User context (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4011).